# AsyncTask: where does the return value of doInBackground() go?

Tags: android, return-value, android-asynctask

When calling `AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Boolean>`, where is the return value of:

`protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)`?

Usually we start AsyncTask with `new AsyncTaskClassName().execute(param1,param2......);` but it doesn't appear to return a value.

Where can the return value of `doInBackground()` be found?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The value is then available in [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) which you may want to override in order to work with the result.

Here is example code snippet from Google's docs:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
      protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
          int count = urls.length;
          long totalSize = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
              publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
          }
          return totalSize;
      }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
          setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
      }
 }
```

Comment: To make this of any real use other than logging or showing a dialog, you can nest the class you extend `AsyncTask` with in your UI (or other) class and then call a method from that class with the return value in the `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 36):

You can retreive the return value of protected Boolean `doInBackground()` by calling the [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method of `AsyncTask` class :

```
AsyncTaskClassName task = new AsyncTaskClassName();
bool result = task.execute(param1,param2......).get();
```

But be careful of the responsiveness of the UI, because `get()` waits for the computation to complete and **will block the UI thread**.
If you are using an inner class, it's better to do the job into the onPostExecute(Boolean result) method.

If you just want to update the UI, `AsyncTask` offers you two posibilites :

To update the UI in parallel with the task executed in `doInBackground()` (e.g. to update a `ProgressBar`), you'll have to call `publishProgress()` inside the `doInBackground()` method. Then you have to update the UI in the `onProgressUpdate()` method.

To update the UI when the task is done, you have to do it in the `onPostExecute()` method.

```
/** This method runs on a background thread (not on the UI thread) */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    for (int progressValue = 0; progressValue  < 100; progressValue++) {
        publishProgress(progressValue);
    }
}

/** This method runs on the UI thread */
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progressValue) {
    // TODO Update your ProgressBar here
}

/**
 * Called after doInBackground() method
 * This method runs on the UI thread
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   // TODO Update the UI thread with the final result
}
```

This way you don't have to care about responsiveness problems.

Comment: this is nor right way .get() will freeze the UI can you sugges any other option i wan to use return result of async task then want to exucute other web servecice pls help me

Comment: If you read my post beyond the fifth line, you will see that I recommend the use of `OnPostExecute()` rather than the `get()` to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: ya but i want to use return value and on the base of return value i want to call multiple url then what can i do pls help me

Comment: Then you have to define a AsyncTask that returns the type you want. Probably a String instead of a boolean : `private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, int[], String>` (the last parameter define the result type). Then you can deduce and call your urls from onPostExecute(String result).

Comment: very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: if you are going to pause the current thread, why would you even use `AsyncTask` in first place?