# Return multiple values from doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

How do I return multiple links I get from this website? The return I have outside the loop doesn't seem to work.

```
public class jsoupexample extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... html) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(html[0]).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");

        for(Element links : link) {
            audi=links.attr("abs:href");
        }
        return audi;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv2.setText(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must try to get all those values and collect them in a list or String array object, using your for loop, and then return that object in **doInBackground**, so that you can later use in your **onPostExecute**.

Use [AsyncTask: where does the return value of doInBackground() go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489399/asynctask-where-return-value-of-doinbackground-goes) for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just add plus Symbol to concat the values like this

```
  for(Element links : link) {
            audi+=links.attr("abs:href");
        }
```

Comment: i'll try  this ! thnxx !