# Android: Viewpager OnPageChangeListener onpageselected disturbs slide animation

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've seen some similar posts here but no appropriate answer.

I use the event **onpageselected in a viewpager** to execute a function. This function is network dependent so it can take some time. But then the slide animation looks laggy.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                makeSomeHeavyTask();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
```

Heavy Task:

```
public void makeSomeHeavyTask() {
        handler.post(new QueryRunnable());

    }
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Any chance we can see the code?

Comment: Are you doing the "heavyTask" in a separate thread without affecting the main UI?

Comment: @MartinCazares That's the code I was inquiring about :)

Comment: yes it should be in a separate thread.

Comment: `handler.post(new QueryRunnable());` will NOT run QueryRunnable() on another thread if the handler was created on the mainLooper (e.g. in an Activity/Fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the heavy task with an `AsyncTask`. Check out the accepted answer here [AsyncTask: where does the return value of doInBackground() go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489399/asynctask-where-return-value-of-doinbackground-goes)

**EDIT:** You need to return a placeholder in the `getView` first. If the `getView` method has to wait for the thread to finish, then the animation will lag for sure. The returned placeholder can later be used to do posting after thread has finished.

Comment: I do it already in another thread through my Handler. ( see in the function makesomeheavytask(). Is there a way to do the slide animation in a async task?!

Comment: Animation can only be done in the UI/main thread. Everything else you can offload to threads.

Comment: Well that only works if your heavy task has does not maniupulate UI, if you want to change Views when page changes you out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i)
```

instead of  `public void onPageSelected(int i)` with

```
if(i == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    //your task
}
```

if you have a task that cannot be executed on a different thread. This will be called after the animation is finished.